# JPA generated SQL with "fetch first ? rows only" fails with ORA-00933 in Oracle 11g

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa, oracle12c

In a Spring Boot 2.0 project, I have a JpaRepository object with query methods. One query method returns a paginated resultset.

```
Page<Model> findByPartContainingIgnoreCaseAndModelContainingIgnoreCaseAndNeedsUpdateContainingIgnoreCase(String part, String model, String needsUpdate, Pageable pageReguest);
```

This JPA query method runs when querying a Oracle 12c database, with the following SQL:

```
select * from (SQL)  where rownum <= 100
```

The same JPA query method fails with (ORA-00933) when querying a Oracle 11g database, with the following SQL generated:

```
select SQL **fetch first 100 rows only**
```

Why does the same code base generate different SQLs for the different Oracle databases? How can we fix this?

The project uses the ojdbc6 (version - 11.2.0.4) Oracle Driver.

Comment: It seems it generates code for 12c when connected to 11g and the code for 11g when connected to 12c - that sure sounds like a bug. Or you are using the wrong Hibernate dialect in both cases.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The problem was with dialect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was because of the dialect. I had used an older dialect at first - "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect"

The problem was resolved by setting the following dialect in application.properties.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```